# Snap Recyclerview item to Center when loaded

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, horizontal-scrolling, linearlayoutmanager

I am using an infinite scroll for recyclerview with X items which repeats.
Also i want am using **PagerSnapHelper()** to snap the scroll like viewpager.

So initially when the list is loaded the display is like -
[image]

As soon as i start scrolling on either side left or right the **PageSnapHelper()** come in work an snap it like viewpager with center alignment like this - [image]

I want to show recyclerview as like 2nd image when initially loaded. Please tell what to do next to acheive that.

here is the code snipet -

```
linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext,   LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
this.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
adapterCarousel = new AdapterCarousel(mContext, glideRequestManager);
adapterCarousel.setViewType(RECYCLER_VIEW_TYPE_NORMAL);
adapterCarousel.setCarousel(carousel);
this.recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterCarousel);
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
linearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2);
```

Comment: Did you find answer to this question?

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue by using `LinearLayoutManager#scrollToPositionWithOffset(pos, offset)`. I just offset the scroll position by half of the padding between items. This worked for me as my items was the same width as the screen. In your case you need to do some math.

Let's say that your item's width is `W`, your RecyclerView had width `rvW` and the padding between items was `padding` then the amount you want to offset by is given by `(rvW - W)/2 - padding/2` or `(rvW - W - padding)/2`.

Final code:

```
// post to give the recyclerview time to layout so it's width isn't 0
mRecyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
    void run() {
        int padding = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.some_padding);
        int rvWidth = mRecyclerView.getWidth();
        int itemWidth = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.itemWidth);
        int offset = (rvWidth - itemWidth - padding) / 2;
        mLinearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(pos, offset);
    }
});
```

Some optional improvements to the code:

- Instead of posting to the RecyclerView, you can use `View#measure()` and `View#getMeasuredWidth()` or even the display's width if you are certain that the RecyclerView will always fit the screen's width.
- If your RecyclerView's children are variable sized you can get the View via `mLinearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(mLinearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition())` and get it's width that way.

Answer (score 0):

for me using `recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(x);` instead of `linearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(x);` did the trick

Comment: this did not work for me, as my list is infinite with max size `Integer.Max_Value`

Answer (score 0):

```
   linearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition((Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2)-1);
   linearLayoutManager.smoothScrollToPosition(Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2);
```

If there is a better way, please tell me

Comment: When I do this there is a very noticable jerk animation when the activity/fragment first loads which is undesirable.